# assign result of function to variable, only the first time the variable is called PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, function

Hi Im a little stuck with this..

I have a function that generates an openssl_random_sudobytes() string ..

```
public function generate_device_token()
{
  $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64));
  return $token;
}
```

this function is called by $token = generate_device_token();

```
$this->load->model('model_visitorbook_dashboard');
if (isset($_POST['add_this_device'])){
  $token = $this->model_visitorbook_dashboard->generate_device_token();
  $data = array(
    'owner_id' => $this->session->user_id,
    'name' => $this->input->post('devicename'),
    'devicetoken' => $token
  );
  if (!$this->model_visitorbook_dashboard->add_this_device($data))
  {
  $error['error'] = "we're sorry but this device could not be added at this time, please contact support for assitance.";
  $this->load->view('view_visitorbook_error', $error);

  }else{
  $time = intval(10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
  $cookiedata = array(
    'name' => 'vb_dev_token',
    'value' => $token,
    'expire' => $time,
    'path' => '/'
  );
  var_dump($cookiedata);
  set_cookie($cookiedata);
  redirect('dashboard/devices', 'refresh');
  }
```

The code is functioning but the second time I call $token (in set_cookie($cookiedata)) a second string is appended to the first one.

how can i get $tokens value to remain static once populated.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note I fixed this.

it turned out that bin2hex(openssl_random_sudo_bytes(64)), actually returns a 128 char string, my database field was set to a length of 64 so the string was being trimmed **Face Palm*.

I changed bin2hex(openssl_random_sudo_bytes(32)), which gave me the 64 char string I was after.

:)